# Unable to detect changes for shadow properties in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get changes for properties, but there is a problem with [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties), both `CurrentValue` and `OriginalValue` are null, is there any alternative for shadow properties?

```
var entities = _context
    .ChangeTracker
    .Entries()
    .ToArray();

foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    foreach (var property in entity.Properties)
    {
        if (property.Metadata.IsShadowProperty())
        {
            var newValue = property.CurrentValue;  // null
            var oldValue = property.OriginalValue; // null
        }
    }
}
```

Entity Classes:

```
public class ParentEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public OwnedEntity SomeEntity { get; set; }
    private string _name;

    public ParentEntity(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        _name = name;
        SomeEntity = new OwnedEntity();
    }
}

public class OwnedEntity 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public OwnedEntity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Name = "Some Name";
    }
}
```

configuration:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ParentEntity> builder)
{
    builder.HasPartitionKey(x => x.PartitionKey);

    builder.Property("_name").ToJsonProperty("name");
    builder.Property(x => x.Id).ToJsonProperty("id");

    builder.OwnsOne(x => x.SomeEntity, x =>
        {
            x.ToJsonProperty("someEntity");
            x.Property(x => x.Id).ToJsonProperty("id");
            x.Property(x => x.Name).ToJsonProperty("name");
        });

    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.HasDiscriminator();

    builder.ToContainer("container1");
}
```

Comment: Can you show the entity class with shadow field?

Comment: @vernou sure, updated.

Comment: What shadow property are we talking about? Because all I see is "owned entity", and no shadow properties, except probably the "FK" to to owner, but it shouldn't mutate (as it is also a "PK" of the owned entity). Also it's good to see the code which introduces a tracking entry - is  it by loading from database, or attaching disconnected entity etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev for "OwnedEntity" property instance "property.Metadata.IsShadowProperty()" returns true. my problem is why CurrentValue, OriginalValue are null for that property!

Comment: Can you display the shadow property name?

Comment: @vernou "property.Metadata.IsShadowProperty()" for "SomeEntity" returns true

Comment: And for `property.Name` ?

Comment: @vernou property.Metadata.Name is "__jObject"

Comment: Hmm, usually owned entities are not included in `Properties` at all. may be `ToJsonProperty` does something I'm unaware of. Actually I don't see such method, looks like it is specific to [Cosmos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.cosmospropertybuilderextensions.tojsonproperty?view=efcore-5.0)